# Converting "2017-06-23T07:15:00" to 23-06-2017 and 07:15 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, datetime

I want to convert "2017-06-23T07:15:00" to 23-06-2017 and 07:15 using jQuery.

Comment: include you have tried so far

Comment: Do you have it in Date format?

Comment: yes it in date time format

Answer (score 1):

User `Date` function to create Object from string and get DateTime elements from created object. An example here:

```js
var d = new Date('2017-06-23T07:15:00');

var year = d.getFullYear(),
    month = d.getMonth() + 1,
    day = d.getDate(),
    hour = d.getHours(),
    minute = d.getMinutes();
    
month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
hour = hour < 10 ? '0' + hour : hour;
minute = minute < 10 ? '0' + minute : minute;

var date = day + '-' + month + '-' + year,
  time = hour + ':' + minute;

alert('Date: ' + date + ' and Time: ' + time);
```

Comment: Hey I am getting it in this format "2017-06-23T07:15:00"

Comment: Oh yes! Updated as per your requirement.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDate(d) {
    if (d != null)
        var date = new Date(d);
    else
        var date = new Date();

    var str = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    return str;
}
```

Hi, you need to convert date like this maybe it helps you. try it now.